# Unity - Pass updating vector3 over GetComponent to move an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

Unity3D Version 4.5.3f3 Pro.

I'm new to Unity and C# and I'm struggling to understand why my object isn't updating (moving) to the new Vector3 value I'm trying to send.

**Background:** I'm passing in an array of 3 values using sockets into unity. I receive the values just fine when doing a Debug.Log of the data. The data updates on a set time incrementing each second (ie. "Position" : "-10, 10, 10" a second later "Position" : "-11, 11, 11" and so on)

I have struggled understanding Vector3 but have come up with this.

**Empty object with Script:**

```
public void PlayerMove(SocketIOEvent e)
{
    Debug.Log("e.data: " + e.data);

    string newVectorString = e.data.ToString ();
    Debug.Log("newVectorString: " + newVectorString);

    string[] temp = newVectorString.Split(',');
    float x = float.Parse(temp[0]);
    float y = float.Parse(temp[1]);
    float z = float.Parse(temp[2]);

    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(x,y,z);
    otherPlayer.GetComponent<OtherPlayer>().startPosition = newPosition;
}
```

Results of the two logs (which are constantly updating) are:

```
e.data: {"Position":"-19,19,0"}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

and

```
newVectorString: {"Position":"-19,19,0"}
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

So I'm receiving data yay! and I have moved it into string 'newVectorString'. I'm then attempting to create a new vector by splitting the string and passing that over GetComponent as follows...

```
otherPlayer.GetComponent<OtherPlayer>().startPosition = newPosition;
```

Next part.

**Object "otherPlayer" with script 'OtherPlayer.cs':**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class OtherPlayer : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public Vector3 startPosition;
 public Vector3 currentPosition = Vector3.zero;

 void Start () 
 {

 }

 void Update () 
 {

    Debug.Log("Is there anybody out there??: " + startPosition.ToString ());

    if (startPosition != Vector3.zero) 
    {
        currentPosition = startPosition;
        startPosition = Vector3.zero;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, currentPosition, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, currentPosition, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
 }
}
```

The result of the latest Debug 'startPosition.ToString ()':

```
Is there anybody out there??: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

- How can I pass these values in correctly
- How can I confirm they are in vector3 format

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: i found this to be a good refresher http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingVectorArithmetic.html

Comment: Thank you. This is handy as I'll be moving to a point which is the average of three or more vectors rather than an single vector further down the track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vector3 vec = otherPlayer.position;
```

this will copy the value of position into vec. Now you have two independent duplicates. Changing one will not affect the other.

You need to keep a reference to PlayerMove in OtherPlayer and track the changes of position.

```
public class OtherPlayer : MonoBehaviour{
    private OtherScript script= null;
    private void Start(){
        this.script= GetOtherScript(); // you should know how to get it 
    }
    void Update () 
 {

    Debug.Log("Is there anybody out there??: " + this.script.startPosition.ToString ());

    if (startPosition != Vector3.zero) 
    {
        currentPosition = this.script.startPosition;
        startPosition = Vector3.zero;
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, currentPosition, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, currentPosition, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
 }
}
```

Don't worry about performance because one level higher nor memory, this is absolutely nothing.

EDIT: To explain further on why:

Consider you have a paper A with (10,10,10) and you take paper B and read the values and write them onto paper B. Now A and B read (10,10,10). Change paper A to (20,20,20), paper B has no reason to change automatically, so it is still (10,10,10). This is what you are doing.

```
 Vector3 currentPosition = newPosition;
```

To fix the issue, take paper A and write (10,10,10) on it, then put it on the desk. Take a paper O and write (desk) on it. Now take a paper W and write (O, Paper B) on it. W has a method that will use O to write on B. So it goes to read on O, O tells desk, then you go the desk and read (10,10,10) and write that on B. All is well.

You update A to (20,20,20), paper W runs the method again, it goes to O that tells Desk, you go to the desk to find A and read (20,20,20) and writes it over on B. Tadaaaa. It works fine. As you can see it is a bit slower but nothing that will affect your performance. This is the case I tell to use.

```
 Vector3 currentPosition = scriptTransform.position;
```

scriptTransform is the paper O position is the paper A on the desk. currentPosition is the paperB. W is the OtherPlayer script.

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful, sure to be the answer. I'm confused about where and why Vector3 vec = otherPlayer.position; is required. I'm working on the rest now. Is this getting the initial position of the object or every new position and it's putting it where? :S Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, thanks for the additional explanation. I got this working with your help!

Answer (score 1):

You OtherPlayer script seems alright: it will smoothly move the gameObject to a certain position whenever you edit startPosition (although you didn't name your variable in a very understandable way:

`startPosition` should be something like `newTargetPosition`

`currentPosition` should be something like `targetPosition`

`transform.Position` is always the exact position of the object (in case it wasn't clear for you)

**What I think you should check:** (see the comments)

```
public void PlayerMove(SocketIOEvent e)
{
    Debug.Log("e.data: " + e.data);

    string newVectorString = e.data.ToString ();
    Debug.Log("newVectorString: " + newVectorString);

    // CHECK THIS: 
    // temp[0] is equal to {"Position":"-19        --> Won't parse 
    string[] temp = newVectorString.Split(',');
    float x = float.Parse(temp[0]);
    float y = float.Parse(temp[1]);
    float z = float.Parse(temp[2]);

    Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(x,y,z);

    // Check this: print new position to see if it is correct
    // Check if otherPlayer is the object you expect to have here
    otherPlayer.GetComponent<OtherPlayer>().startPosition = newPosition;
}
```